# How to rename a FTP folder using FTPclient from CodeProject in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ftp, directory, rename

i'm currently using FTP Client library from codeproject(https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ListVersions.aspx?aid=11991)
And i cannot figure out how to rename a FTP folder, using their library.

Did some research on google and also could not find a way to do this in vb.net,
the code i'm using to try to achive this task is:

```
Dim myFtp As New FTPclient(hostname, username, password)
                myFtp.CurrentDirectory = "/UDB/"
                myFtp.FtpRename("/UDB/" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & "/", TextBox2.Text)
```

That shows me an error on the server as:
(not logged in) (::1)>
But in a fact, i am logged in, as i can lunch another task with same credentials and upload and download functions work fine. 
Is there a way to achieve this using FtpWebRequest? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: So I looked at the GitHub this has been migrated to: https://github.com/conficient/ftpclient/blob/master/FtpClient/FtpClientVB/FtpClient.vb#L482 .  I believe FtpRename is only for files?

Comment: Looks like it is, anyway to rename a FTP folder?

Comment: With the .Net `FtpWebRequest`, using `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename` as method, you can use the [RenameTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.renameto) property to specify the new name of the directory you asked for in the request. Just the name, not the full path. Some servers may not accept to rename a directory that is not empty. -- Since you have [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) here, you could also click on his gravatar and follow the link to WinSCP.